# print data in an array of structs recursively

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, recursion, struct

I need to print the data in an array of structs recursively like so,

```
index, numberOfChildern, child[0]...child[numberOfChildern-1]
```

The catch is that for every child, I need to print `index, numberOfChildern, child[0]...child[numberOfChildern-1]` as well.

```
typedef struct node point;
typedef point **pointsList;
```

The struct:

```
struct node{
  int index; //the order in the instance file
  int x;//x coord
  int y;//y coord
  int parent;//parent in tree when added
  int numChildern;//has val 0 -- 8 maybe, but doesn't matter the way I wrote it
  int *child;    
};
```

All values in every struct is set properly, This is a incomplete method I began writing to complete the task.

```
void printStringOfChildern(pointsList list, point *point, int fileNum){


if(point->numChildern == 0)
    return;

  //print the index
  char index[calcNumberOfDigitsInAInt(point->index)+3];
  sprintf(index, "%d", point->index);
  strcat(index, ", ");
  print(index, fileNum);

  //print the number of childern
  char chidern[calcNumberOfDigitsInAInt(point->numChildern)+3];
  sprintf(chidern, "%d", point->numChildern);
  strcat(chidern, ", ");
  print(chidern, fileNum);

  //print the childern
  for(int i=0; i<point->numChildern; i++){
    char child[calcNumberOfDigitsInAInt(point->child[i])+3];

//was child[i] now point->child[i]
    sprintf(child, "%d", point->child[i]);
    strcat(child, ", ");
    print(child, fileNum);

    //print out other childern and their data if there is any
    int numChildern = numberOfChildern(list, point -> index);
    if(numChildern > 0){
      printStringOfChildern(list, list[point->child[i]], fileNum);

    }

  }

}
```

You'll notice the above code is awful and incomplete, but it shows the use of my printing functions

The if else block below is how I print to the output, which could be terminal a file or a series of files. The print functions and this if else block have been tested, and proven to work. inOutType is a global variable, and so is outputFileName. fileIndex is only used in the case of printing to multiple files and in the case of printing to multiple files this method will be called for however many files there are. This is the print function

```
if(inOutType == 1 || inOutType == 2){
printLineToOutPut(output, outputFileName, inOutType);

}else{
    printToAInstanceFile(output, fileIndex);

  }
```

All I've done in the edits is update the sample, and write this

```
Output format:



index, numberOfChildern, child[i]. If child[i] has children then index, numberOfChildern, indexOf(child[i]), numberOfChildernOf(child[i]), child[i]OfChild[i].....
```

The method is executed like so

```
for(int j=0; j<maxNumberOfPoints; j++)
        printStringOfChildern(listOfListOfPoints[i], listOfListOfPoints[i][j], i);
```

Comment: First learn the basics, like how `strcat()` works and how `sprintf()` is unsafe. Also, avoid global variables! And learn the important skill of debugging.

Comment: mostly just want to see if someone would figure it out faster, I'm writing it right now. strcat and sprintf are unsafe if you don't calculate the string size as I have done. Using global variables is simpler in this instance. I've left out 90% of the code. @iharob

Comment: Please don't use spaces around the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators.  They bind very tightly and spaces around them are aconventional at best, and suggest that the author of the code is a novice C programmer.  (Also, in English, the plural of 'child' is 'children' rather than 'childern'.)

Comment: You should really show a simple example — perhaps a parent with 3 children, of which the middle one has 2 grandchildren of the parent.  What should the output look like?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I added the updates, and it is working almost right now. It prints the children of the point it is passed, but not the children of that child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the absence of a clear example of what the output should look like, here's a version of the code shown.  Note that I simply create buffers that are 32 characters long rather than spending time calculating exactly how long they must be.  That's not a lot of memory and yet plenty for the task at hand.  Also, there was no data — I've invented some:

```
Index 0:  3 children
    Index 1: 0 children
    Index 2: 2 children
        Index 4: 0 children
        Index 5: 0 children
    Index 3: 0 children
```

There's no need for any other data; the `x`, `y` and `parent` members of the structure in the question aren't used — eliminating the irrelevant is a part of creating an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

I've ignored the 'fileNum' argument; the printing occurs simply and solely to standard output.  It is easy enough to reinstate printing to a file if you need it.  I've also used a notation inspired by JSON to report the data, enclosing arrays in `[…]` and single points except for the top of the hierarchy inside `{…}`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node point;
typedef point **pointsList;

struct node
{
    int index; // the order in the instance file
    // int x;//x coord
    // int y;//y coord
    // int parent;//parent in tree when added
    int numChildren;// has val 0 -- 8 maybe, but doesn't matter the way I wrote it
    int *child;
};

static inline void print(const char *str)
{
    printf("%s", str);
}

static void printStringOfChildren(pointsList list, point *point)
{
    // print the index
    char index[32];
    sprintf(index, "%d", point->index);
    strcat(index, ", ");
    print(index);

    // print the number of children
    char children[32];
    sprintf(children, "%d", point->numChildren);
    strcat(children, ", ");
    print(children);

    // print the children
    print("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < point->numChildren; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
            print(",");
        print(" { ");
        printStringOfChildren(list, list[point->child[i]]);
        print(" }");
    }
    if (point->numChildren > 0)
        print(" ");
    print("]");
}

int main(void)
{
    point *list[] =
    {
        &(point){ 0, 3, (int[]){ 1, 2, 3 } },
        &(point){ 1, 0, 0 },
        &(point){ 2, 2, (int[]){ 4, 5 } },
        &(point){ 3, 0, 0 },
        &(point){ 4, 0, 0 },
        &(point){ 5, 0, 0 },
    };
    printStringOfChildren(list, list[0]);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0, 3, [ { 1, 0, [] }, { 2, 2, [ { 4, 0, [] }, { 5, 0, [] } ] }, { 3, 0, [] } ]
```

There are many other ways to do the output.  The whole business with `sprintf()` and `strcat()` is bogus — you could perfectly well use `printf()` in my scenario, or `fprintf()` in a more general case, to format the data, reducing the size of the program still more.

Comment: Good input, I'll give you the points for the work, and information. The way the struct is made is needed for the assignment. I like the suggestion to fprintf. Next time I'll word it a bit better I tried to include as little code as possible because the whole program is 2000 lines +. Also, the print needs to print to a list of files, a single file, or stdout. I handled it all in a greasy manner. Not marked for the way it is written and it is due in 5 hours